# set calling argument to None inside function

Tags: python

How can I make a python function act on the original object that is given as an argument,

```
def f(x):
    x = None

y = 1
f(y)
y  # Returns 1, I want y to return None
```

I know that y == 1 is the correct behaviour. My question is: is there a trick that makes it possible to have a python function behave as if the argument were passed by reference?

Comment: You cannot rebind names outside the scope of the function, not without dirty trickery that only works in limited cases.

Comment: That's what I really wanted to know: is there some dirty trickery that allows me to obtain a similar effect?

Answer (score 1):

```
def f(x):
    return None

y = 1
y = f(y)
y  # Returns 1, I want y to return None
```

You need to return from a function and assign the return to a variable

Answer (score 0):

Your function `f(x)` doesn't actually return anything. When you set `x = None`, all you're doing is reassigning the local `x` that's inside `f`; you're not actually changing the variable that you passed in. That's not something you can do very easily in Python, and you usually don't want to. You'd want something like:

```
def f(x):
  x = None
  return x
```

And then assign `y` to `f(x)` in your main code.